# How can I plot the "sol" in the following?

Tags: plotting, graphics, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to plot the following differential equation for different values of P but no succes:

```
A0 = 1; B0 = 25; L0 = 1; f = 25; tmax = 1;
P = 50; k = 0.235; Cx = 4.2; Rho = 1 ; r = 0.001; L = 0.006;
Q = Rho/(Pi * r^2 * NIntegrate[Exp[-k/(P*Cx)], {x, 0, 1.25*10^-6}]);
 (*solve steady state*)
uE = u[x] /. First@DSolve[{u''[x] == 0, u[L0] == B0, u'[0] == A0}, u[x], x];

 (*solve trasnient state*)
 ic = v[x, 0] == f - uE;
 bc1 = v[L0, t] == 0;
 bc2 = Derivative[1, 0][v][0, t] == 0;
 sol = v[x, t] /. 
  First@DSolve[{P*Cx*D[v[x, t], t] == (K^2)* D[v[x, t] + Q, {x, 2}], 
  ic, bc1, bc2}, v[x, t], {x, t}];
 sol = sol /. {K[1] -> n, Infinity -> 1000};
 (*-terms seems enough*)(*add solutions*)
 sol = sol + uE
```

Comment: Please post actual Mathematica CODE, people cannot copy it from the image and should not be retyping such complex expressions. Look up [Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) in docs and show  your own effort and code with plotting even if you cannot get it right. It is easier to see then what is not working out for you.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For plotting all your parameters need to be numerically defined. Please read docs a bit on plotting as this is quite simple. You got `Inactive` sum that you should `Activate`. Use `Evaluate` inside plotting functions to speedup plotting up. Read up docs on all functions I mentioned and used.

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Activate[sol /. K -> 1]], {x, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "T"}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Activate[sol /. {K -> 1, t -> 1}]], {x, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "T"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have another question how can I make Assumptions -> Mod[n, 2] == 1 when I plot the figure?